# Django polymorphic и GenericRelation. Как получить все связанные объекты?

Tags: python, django

models.py

```
class File(models.Model):--> content_type_id=4
    is_recorded = models.BooleanField(verbose_name=_('is recorded'), default=False)
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    content_object = GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')


class Parent(PolymorphicModel): --> content_type_id=1
    files = GenericRelation(File)
    field0 = models.CharField(verbose_name=_('field0'), max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)

class Child1(Parent): --> content_type_id=2
    field1 = models.CharField(verbose_name=_('field1'), max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)

class Child2(Parent): --> content_type_id=3
    field2 = models.CharField(verbose_name=_('field2'), max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
```

Запуск 1

```
Parent.object.all()
[ <Child1:  id 1>,
  <Child2:  id 2>]
```

SQL 2

```
SELECT `parent`.`id`,    
   `parent`.`polymorphic_ctype_id`,
   `parent`.`content_type_id`,
   `parent`.`object_id`,
   `parent`.`fiedl0`,
FROM `events_event`
```

**Все окей**

---

Запуск 2

```
Child2.object.filter(files__is_recorded=True)
[<Child2:   id 1>]
```

SQL 2

```
SELECT DISTINCT `parent`.`id`,
            `parent`.`polymorphic_ctype_id`,
            `parent`.`content_type_id`,
            `parent`.`object_id`,
            `child2`.`parent_ptr_id`,
            `child2`.`field1`,
FROM `child2`
     INNER JOIN `parent` ON (`child2`.`parent_ptr_id` = `parent`.`id`)
     INNER JOIN `parent` T3
                ON (`child2`.`parent_ptr_id` = T3.`object_id` AND (T3.`content_type_id` = 2))
     INNER JOIN `file` ON (T3.`id` = `file`.`id`)
```

**Все окей**

---

Запуск 3

```
Parent.object.filter(files__is_recorded=True)
[]
```

SQL 3

```
SELECT DISTINCT `parent`.`id`,
            `parent`.`polymorphic_ctype_id`,
            `parent`.`content_type_id`,
            `parent`.`object_id`,
FROM `parent`
     INNER JOIN `file`
                ON (`parent`.`id` = `file`.`object_id` AND (`file`.`content_type_id` = 1))
```

**Не ок**

Как получить все подъобъекты (Child1, Child2) с фильтром files__is_recorded=True (без добавления еще одного GenericForeignKey в модель File со ссылкой на модель Parent)?

Comment: Может, пойти таким путем, в духе `File.objects.filter(content_type=Parent,is_recorded=True)`?

Comment: Странно, что джанго в последнем запросе сформировал content_type_id=12

Comment: content_type_id=12  -  это я накосячил, когда копировал.

Comment: File.objects.filter(content_type=Parent,is_recorded=True) - Это получается тот же запрос, и ничего не найдет, т.к. content_type в модели File будет указывать на Child1 и на Child2

Comment: Я вижу что эту проблему можно решить следующим образом - добавить в Parent поле files_parent = GenericRelation(File,   
    content_type_field='parent_content_type_id',
    object_id_field='parent_object_id',), и соответствующие поля в модель File. При сохранении файла - проставлять parent_content_object на Parent, а content_object на ChildX. Тогда я смогу сделать запрос Parent.object.filter(files_parent__is_recorded=True) и получить то что мне нужно. Но это прям не хочется делать, т.к. выглядит очень криво.

Comment: а как вы с File работаете, когда присваиваете content_object? Может его перед этим к Parent приводить?

Comment: Да по сути так и сделал, лучшего решения не придумал